# SQL query for comparing if monthly purchase amounts increase or decrease

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am working on a report that should tell me if there was any increase or decrease in the purchase amounts between the months of January and December. There is one record for each instance of the account, so typically there would be anywhere from 4 (if quarterly), to 12 (if monthly) records per customer. How do I make a SQL query that would do something like this? It would basically have to look over all of the months and tell if there was a change in any of the months.

This is what I currently have:

```
Yr/Mnth  Amt    
1212    51.00   
1209    69.00  
1206    69.00       
1203    69.00
```

This is what I would like to see:

```
March    June    September   December    Amount Diff  Increase or Decrease
69.00    69.00    69.00        51.00        18.00          Decrease
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably for your report you can use this

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Yr/Mnth]) AS Id
  FROM dbo.purchase
  )
  SELECT DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(mm, RIGHT(c1.[Yr/Mnth],2)-1, '20010101')) AS [Month], 
         c1.Amt, ISNULL(c2.Amt, c1.Amt) - c1.Amt AS 'Amount Diff', 
         CASE WHEN c2.Amt - c1.Amt > 0 THEN 'Decrease'
              WHEN c2.Amt - c1.Amt < 0 THEN 'Increase'                   
              ELSE '' END AS 'Increase or Decrease'
  FROM cte c1 LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c1.Id = c2.Id + 1
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1cd44/3)

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
select case when amount1 > amount2 then 'increase'
when amount2 < amount1 then 'decrease'
else 'no change'
end changetype
from 
(select t1.something amount1, t2.somethingelse amount2
from yourtable t1 join yourtable t2 on something
etc) alias_required
```

You should be able to fill in the blanks.